# Overload Baseform

Tags: c#, overloading

How do i use overload in C#

I have a sample codes that goes like this

```
Namespace Test
Partial Class TestAccess
    Inherits BaseForm

    Dim db As New database
    Dim share As New ShareMethod

    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        MyBase.Page_Load(sender, e)
```

I tried using the converter, but keep getting error.

And my overload doesnt have any function, so do i still use .....+....

****UPDATED

Here is my codes for the program which i want to inherit

```
namespace CRRBaseForm
```

{

```
public partial class TAView : BaseForm
{
    protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            binddropdownlists();
        }
    }
```

currently nothing happens. 
but when i did this; it tells me that i need to overload:

```
    namespace CRRBaseForm
{

    public partial class TAView : BaseForm
    {
        protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {
                Page_Load(); //call from BaseForm
                binddropdownlists();
            }
        }
```

my baseform is as follow:

```
namespace CRRBaseForm
{

public partial class BaseForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected virtual void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if the Session Login id null
        if (Session["UserID"] == null)
        {...
...
...
```

Comment: What C# does the converter produce?

Comment: And what error are you getting? And what do you mean by "my overload doesn't have any function"?

Comment: Is the Page_Load function marked with virtual keyword in BaseForm?

Comment: Yes. in the baseform there is a keyword as follows:
public partial class BaseForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected virtual void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Check if the Session Login id null
        if (Session["UserID"] == null)
        {....
.....
.....

Answer (score 1):

In C#, it is like so:

```
protected override void Load (object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
}
```

Assuming a 'Load' `virtual` or `abstract` method in the parent class.

-- Edit

You've updated your question, and you have this:

```
Page_Load(); //call from BaseForm
```

That actually needs to be:

```
base.Page_Load(); //call from BaseForm
```

Otherwise it will just call itself recursively.

Comment: You are missing a return type in your method signature.

Comment: I've updated the post slightly, as you have a problem in the posted code; but the overriding should work. Please show the actual compilation error you are getting.

Comment: when i've done that, i have this error which is the same error.
Dont quite understand the error though
No overload for method 'Page_Load' takes '0' arguments

Comment: I don't understand how the code you have shown is producing that error.

Comment: I know why. Because there is no parameter. 
So, i insert this: base.Page_Load(sender,e);
But, still never inherit anything from the baseform. :((((